# Count entries between given values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following Excel table. I want to count the number of cells between two 0.1 values in column A. I am not able to make a perfect code. I have tried with `if`, `vlookup`, also `search` and `count`. Please help me with the correct formula. I have 20000 cells to count.

[image: Excel table A and B]

Comment: Please check the pic for details

Answer (score 0):

Activate the Auto-Filter, and filter for 'not 0.1'. In the bottom left, it will tell you the number of matching lines. No need for formulas.

Comment: Thanks sir for the comment,  I had done as you have said but but I need the number of cells between 2 consecutive 0.1 values.

Comment: Actually it is time, each cell is 1 sec. and 0.1 is the change. So I have looking for change/time for  my further analysis.